# How to synchronize static field in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I want to have objects with different IDs when they are initialized. For example, suppose I have a class called "Object"

```
public class Object {
   public:
      int id;
      static int tmp;
      Object() {
          id = tmp++;
      }
}

int Object::tmp = 0;
```

Basically, I want to assign unique IDs to the objects initialized from class `Object` by increasing the value of static field `tmp`. It should work when there is only one thread. But what should I do to synchronize the static field `tmp` when there are multiple threads in which `Object` can be initialized.

Comment: Use a mutex, which you will find in the standard library. Also C++ doesn't have any constructs like this: `public class Object`

Comment: Use `std::atomic<int>` instead of `int`.

Comment: The current code also risks running into initialization order fiasco. What if someone tries to create an instance of `Object` (as part of some other global initialization) before the `int Object::tmp = 0` initialization has happened?

Comment: `public class Object {` is not standard `c++` is this `c++-cli`?

Comment: @nwp The `int` indeed needs to be atomic. However I think the code could still run into inconsistent state, when two threads would try to do `id = tmp++` at the same time. This could be resolved by doing some atomic increment or having a mutex.

Comment: @Jeysym Why would that cause an inconsistent state? The `tmp++` is done atomically and `id` is an unshared variable.

Comment: @nwp Oh my bad. I overlooked that `id` is not shared. ;)

Comment: @drescherjm, you said, "...not standard C++." Are you saying that only because of the initial `public` keyword? 'cause if you take that `public` away, then everything else in the snippet compiles and behaves as you would expect.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Sorry my mistake...I'm more familiar with Java so I accidently add the public keywords...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what should I do to synchronize the static field tmp when there are multiple threads in which Object can be initialized.

You should use `std::atomic<unsigned>` for the counter to make incrementing it thread-safe. `unsigned` to guarantee that wrapping the counter won't result in undefined behaviour.

```
class Object {
    static std::atomic<unsigned> tmp;
public:
    unsigned const id = tmp.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
};

std::atomic<unsigned> Object::tmp{0};
```

Note that initialization of `Object::tmp` happens at *static* initialization phase before the *dynamic* initialization invokes any constructor of any global object.

---

A more effective strategy is to use thread-specific counters, so that the threads do not contend on incrementing the shared counter.

Comment: Should it be std::atomic<unsigned int>?

Comment: @RichardHu `unsigned int` and `unsigned` is the same type.